# Python - Indexing, comparing and appending

Tags: python, list, indexing, int, append

I struggled in naming the title of the question, as you can tell.. Anyways, to put the question into some context: I have a high-scores text file, the data has been put into a list. The scores of each individual have been sorted so they now order from lowest to highest.

```
data = [['Stuart', 'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '92'], [ 'Steve', 
         'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '53'], ['Andrew', 'got', 'a', 
         'highscore', 'of:', '73'], ['Luke', 'got', 'a', 'highscore', 
         'of:', '1'], [ 'Shaney', 'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '77'], 
        ['Robert', 'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '33'], ['Moley', 
         'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '6'], [ 'Kev', 'got', 'a', 
         'highscore', 'of', '2322']]
numbers = [1, 6, 33, 53, 73, 77, 92, 2322]
temp = []
```

I am aiming to create a list called "temp" that contains the *ordered data*. The "ordered data" would be the original date, but arranged so that `['Luke', 'got', 'a', 'highscore', 'of:', '1']` would be at the beginning of the "temp" list.

As usual, any feedback that would help me out will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = sorted(data, key= lambda s: int(s[-1]))
```

I think this will work, I didn't test it though

Comment: It just had to be converted into an integer. Thanks so much for the response though, I've literally been ages trying to figure it out, much appreciated man.

Answer (score 3):

sort making sure to cast to  int or "100000" will be sorted before "2":

```
 print(sorted(data,key=lambda x:int(x[-1])))
```

If you really want to store the last entry  as an int in your output list:

```
temp =  [x[:-1]+[int(x[-1])] for x in sorted(data,key=lambda x:int(x[-1]))]
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, added both

Comment: @BhargavRao LMAO. I was thinking the same thing... but I didn't want to say it... anyway, +1 for complete answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao, lucky this is a programming and not a spelling site ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You should have been on http://english.stackexchange.com/ ... You would have been downvoted like hell

Comment: Awarded as the answer just due to answering the question beyond the extent requested and explaining well. Thank-you for your response.